# How can I make different tables for a nested model join them instead of flatening or changing them to json or string using sqflite?

Tags: flutter, sqflite

So this my entity that I am using. I want to create seprate table for Translations, Questions. So when I insert data in Collection table it automatically populates translations and questions too.

```
class Collection extends Equatable {
final String? id;
final String? workspaceCode;
final String? code;
final String? author;
final String? modifier;
final String? creationTime;
final String? modificationTime;
final String? unitCode;
final bool? shared;
final List<String>? permissions;
final int? version;
final Translations? name;
final Translations? description;
final List<Question>? question;
final String? resourceType;

const Collection({
 this.id,
 this.workspaceCode,
 this.code,
 this.author,
 this.modifier,
 this.creationTime,
 this.modificationTime,
 this.unitCode,
 this.shared,
 this.permissions,
 this.version,
 this.name,
 this.description,
 this.question,
this.resourceType,
```

});